# Jquery chaining different css issues

Tags: jquery

Trying to use css in jquery to define an element and another snipet of code when the mouse hovers over, i cant get either css codes to run.  This is a proposing experiment and already aware CSS is more of use.  This is simply a jquery use only codes.

Here are the jquery codes for a given paragraph with class p.

```
<p class="p"> this is a generic element with generic coding.</p>
```

Here is the jquery end.

```
$("document"). ready( function (){
    var $p = $("p.p");

    $p
        .css({
            "font-size" :  "200%" ,
            "color" : "#030"
        })
       .onhover( function(){
            $p.css({
                "font-size" : "175%" ,
                "color" : "#060"
            });
      });
});
```

Hopefully it will work!  Thank you all for your hard work!

Comment: is `onhover` a jQuery function? what i know is `jQuery.hover()`

Comment: it was i think, its suppose to be for when a mouse hovers over it

Comment: `.onhover` should be `.on("mouseover",function(){...`

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just do this with CSS?

Comment: because i am proposing an experiment on the efectiveness on jquery using both javascript and css.  vs css alone (which i can easily do, but it will defeat the purpose of this experiment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentionned in comment, there is no `onhover` in jQuery. Maybe in raw javascript but you cannot use it that way and apply it to jQuery object.

Use [jQuery.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead:

```
$("document"). ready( function (){
    var $p = $("p.p");

    $p
        .css({
            "font-size" :  "200%" ,
            "color" : "#030"
        })
       .hover( function(){
            $p.css({
                "font-size" : "175%" ,
                "color" : "#060"
            });
      });
});
```

Or you can use `jQuery.on("mouseover", callback)` as suggested by Louys. The two approaches serve your purpose for chainability.

Comment: Does `.hover` needs two handler ? If only one specified, it's the out handler??? I'm not sure but...

Comment: tried the input on w3schools try it yourself.  still not seeing any css on any event

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I don't see what you mean honneslty!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, it is only one callback.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers: I never really used `.hover()`... But your reference states these two possibilities : `.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` and `.hover( handlerInOut )`.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette    Yes, I agree ,  Use the one that  suits your needs

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers: okay! lol I learned something too ! Upvote! ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette,put in other words: I think HOVER= MouseEnter + MouseLeave. Sometimes you need 2 callbacks for the two sepearate events but sometimes you need on callback for the whole hover scenario

Comment: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ze3bogcf/) of the above much better than W3Schools .... note that Document.Ready is handled by jsfiddle

Comment: @GarethCompton,As I understand,  the `jQuery.hover` function was created to accept two different uses: with one callback or using two callbacks if you want to HANDLE 2 behaviours (when mouse enters and when mouse leave)

Comment: @GarethCompton, if you find this answer useful please to accept it

Comment: I tried your answer and still had no css on either events

Comment: so how would i use off and on hover with your fiddle example?  Like specify `.hover({ "on", function(){}, "off", function (){});` ?

Comment: what off and what on? Your syntax is wrong first.. If that exists, you need a closing '}', but i don't see it makes any sense. Please to ask separate question for this because for me, OP issue (CSS + HOVER handling + chainability) is resolved

Comment: the problem was, when inserting and playing with css values, it appears that it doesnt work as effective.  Despite it works exactly like it should but the values differ...  (I also wanted to accept your answer regardless because i learned something new, but i am not rep 15 to upvote :'( )

Comment: I guess not, i got it all messed up, TY whitelettersinblankpapers for your help alongside of Jon and Louys

Comment: You are welcome and I hope you take the advice of Jon seriously. Try to use javascript for things other than styling (well do your best to, since somethings you need to styles things from js). In your situation, I believe CSS is enough.